# Why doesn't the EM field above the center of a charged current loop look like a bivector?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

This is probably a silly mistake.  I know that in relativity the electromagnetic field is a bivector.  But I was thinking about the field on the axis of a circular current loop with a net charge.  By symmetry, both $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ are along the axis, right?  So we only have $E_z$ and $B_z$.  But plugging those into the formula for the Faraday tensor means there are only $F_{tz}$ and $F_{xy}$ components.  So in geometric algebra language:

$\mathbf F = F_{tz}\mathbf e_t\mathbf e_z + F_{xy}\mathbf e_x\mathbf e_y$

But that can't be expressed as a product of orthogonal vectors, can it?  In which case how can it be a single bivector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remark, the fields are along $z$ only when you stay on the axis due to symmetry considerations. In general however, the magnetic field will curve around the loop and the electric field will depart from it generating complicated field lines.

For your main question, are you trying to express $F$ as the exterior product of orthogonal vectors? This is in general not possible, why are you trying to do that? In fact, $E$ and $B$ are not even necessarily orthogonal even in vacuum. After all in the static case, they have independent sources, so just like in your example they can be aligned in some places.

Hope this helps and tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Oh wow, okay, thanks!  I guess I was misinterpreting the term "bivector".  So then...how can we interpret the directionality of the exterior derivative of a vector field in 4D (since we know $\mathbf F = d\mathbf A$)?  In 3D, it is the plane of maximum infinitesimal circulation.  But in 4D in general we get 2 dual planes ($tz$ and $xy$ in my example).  Is a concise description of the significance of these 2 planes possible?  e.g. maybe one is the max circulation and the other is the min?  Or they are both maxes somehow?